# how to get all values from LowCardinality(String) datatype more optimal way?

Tags: clickhouse

i am new to clickhouse,and amazed by clickhosue's performance.

there have one thing bother me, i have a table use LowCardinality(String) type.

DDL like

```sql
create table test.table1(code LowCardinality(String),xxx,xxx,xxx ) engine=MergeTree xxx
```

i want get all distinct value from table.

there is my select query

```sql
select distinct code from test.table1;
```

but the mount of data is quite large, about 14 billion which may take 40s to complete,and is processed all rows in table,

so i wonder if there have any method to get data from LowCardinality datatype?

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```sql
select code /*, count() */
from test.table1
group by code
```

Comment: it work! my select query take 40s.your's only 10s. thanks